# Is the Standard Model fully renormalizable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, renormalization

't Hooft showed that Yang Mills theory with spontaneous gauge symmetry breaking Higgs potential is still renormalizable.

Is the Standard Model fully renormalizable?

The potential issues to addressed in your answer are:

- Includng the electroweak and strong interaction sectors
- The issue of chiral gauge theories.

(previous answer [What do we mean when we say 't Hooft proved that Standard Model is renormalizable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/385389/what-do-we-mean-when-we-say-t-hooft-proved-that-standard-model-is-renormalizabl) does not address the last issue on chiral gauge theories.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do we mean when we say 't Hooft proved that Standard Model is renormalizable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/385389/)

Comment: (previous answer What do we mean when we say 't Hooft proved that Standard Model is renormalizable? does not address the last issue on chiral gauge theories.)

Comment: previous answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/385389/what-do-we-mean-when-we-say-t-hooft-proved-that-standard-model-is-renormalizabl does not address the last issue on chiral gauge theories.

Comment: Most QFT theory books reassure you that ***yes*** all chiral gauge anomalies vanish (cancel) in the SM, which was the major theoretical boost in its acceptance. Perhaps you wish to ask this narrow question individually, but it is standard textbook stuff, as indicated, and has been answered repeatedly.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199520/anomaly-cancellation-in-the-standard-model-calculating-the-symmetrized-trace-of).